# Untar files to destination directories based on tar file names

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, tar

I have a tar file named `_home_rock_files.tar` that was tarred in a source server and now once I copied this tar to destination server I have the same directory structure as `_home_rock_files`. Now, my question arises here.

I want to write a shell script which automatically untars `_home_rock_files.tar` and untars the archive to `/home/rock/files/`; the destination path is specified in the file name like this.

Comment: actually _ is nothing but / .Here how my shell script will know this has to untarred at  /home/rock/files/. I cant hardcode the path all is _home_rock_files.tar is clue for untar destination folder,  tar -xvf _home_rock_files.tar -C /home/rock/files  how this can be achived.

Comment: do you mean, you have several files, and if the file is called `_home_rock_files` it should untar to `/home/rock/files` and if it is called `_hi_there_zanna` it should untar to `/hi/there/zanna`?

Comment: yes you got it.. these are not files these are directory...

Comment: Oh right! Good question, +1. I edited slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this set of bash commands:

```bsh
[sudo] find * -type f -name "SPECIFY THE FILE NAME"| 
    while read FILE ; do       # read the files
        destpath="$(echo "$FILE"| sed 's/_/\//g;s/.tar//')"; #rerplace all _s with /s and drop the .tar ext to achive destpath
        mkdir -p "$destpath";  #create the directory path of despath  
        tar xzf "$FILE" -C "$destpath" ;  #untar the file to destpath
    done
```

Comment: great i will customize according to my needs as in solaris -C will break i need to go through that....

Comment: Initially i was testing on Ubuntu box now same has to dumped on solaris box...